# Approximate (continuous) functions by step functions - Convergence Rate

Tags: functional-analysis, numerical-methods, approximation, approximation-theory

I want to approximate a measurable and bounded function $S:[0,1]^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by step functions. So, assume we have a uniform partition $$
\{I_j\}_{j=1}^n,  \textit{   }  j=1,...,n
$$ of $[0,1]$. Then a step function $S_n$ with $n$ steps is defined as
$$
S_n(u,v) = \sum_{i, j \leq n} a_{i,j}\chi_{I_i}(u) \chi_{I_j}(v).
$$
What (continuity-)conditions do we have to assume for $S$ and how are we supposed to choose the coefficients $a_{i,j}$ to achieve "good" convergence rates for the approximation, for instance
$$
\|S_n - S\|_{L^{2}} \in \mathcal{O}(f(1/n))
$$
for some $f$ (ideally the identity or better) for $n \rightarrow \infty$.

Answer (score 0):

Since
$$ ||S - S_n||_2^2 = \sum_{i,j} \int_{I_i \times I_j} |f - a_{ij}|^2 $$
it's fairly easy to see that the best choice is
$$ a_{ij} = \frac{1}{N^2} \int_{I_i \times I_j} f $$
you can prove this by differentiating
$$ \alpha \in \mathbb{R} : \varphi(\alpha) = \int_{I_i \times I_j} |f - \alpha|^2$$
and noticing it is convex.